# Stream/Show VNC screen using Python/Django to a web page without exposing the port or URL

Tags: python, django, proxy, vnc, tunnel

I have a VNC ([noVNC](https://kanaka.github.io/noVNC/)) server running in my **localhost:port** and also have a Django web application running on **port 80**. I wanted to **stream/show** this VNC (screen) which is running in localhost to one of the web pages which can be seen by the users after they login to the Django web application. I can't embed the vnc page without exposing the port to public IP, if I do that it'll be insecure and anyone with the IP:port can open the noVNC screen.

I wanted to know, **Is there a service/tool/way to stream/show the VNC screen to the users through the Django/Python web page without exposing IP:Port to public?**